# How do I return a list of numbers below a certain threshold without using complex list functions?

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to do this without using complex functions, please help. this is the docstring of the code:

```
 '''
 finds all numbers in the list below a certain threshold
    :param numList: a list of numbers
    :threshold: the cutoff (only numbers below this will be included)
    :returns: a new list of all numbers from numList below the threshold
 '''
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is a "complex function"?

Comment: complex function meaning sum, slice, sort, etc. I tried this: for i in range(len(numList)):
        return numList[i] < threshold.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
"I can't figure out" suggests that you need some time with a programming tutorial or a tutor, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think you are on the right track with a loop. Do you know what conditional statements are? I would add a list variable outside of the loop and then append to the list based on if the condition is met or not. Then return the list after the loop is done looping through.

Comment: `return [x for x in numList if x < threshold]` would be it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach

```
def filterList(numList, threshold):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x < threshold, numList))
```

Another approach:

```
filteredList = [x for x in numList if x < threshold]
```